# How to stop search bar from hiding on scroll

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UINavigationController` that has a `UISearchController` assigned to the navigationItem's `searchController`. Inside the view I have a `UICollectionView`. The search bar displays in the navigation bar, but when I scroll, the navigation bar automatically hides. Can I stop this from happening?

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: recentSearchesViewController)
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = recentSearchesViewController
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
definesPresentationContext = true
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46401725/hideuisearchbarwhenscrolling-property-not-working-with-tableview-as-property/46413757#46413757

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set :

```
navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
```